# Early E&M problem revisited

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws

In my first electromagnetism class we were given this problem: Suppose you take two electrons and bring them within a distance $d$ of each other. Then release them. What is their final velocity?

Early on  it was expected that we would proceed thusly: $$U=\frac{-e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 d}=2(\frac{1}{2})m_ev^2\implies v= \frac{-e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0m_ed}.$$

After we learn that accelerating particles emit radiation, we we find that was an oversimplification. I'm having trouble filling in the gaps though.

$$\frac{-e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 d}=\frac{-e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}+ 2(\frac{1}{2})m_ev(t)^2+S$$ where $S$ is a catchall term for the non-mechanic energy, that is, energy in the radiation field.

Take the time derivative of both sides we have $$0=\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\frac{dr}{dt}+2m_ev \frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{dS}{dt}.$$

This expresses the conservation of energy. If the second and third terms don't cancel, this suggests the coulomb force doesn't fully account for the the force between the two electrons. What is the other force? Is it due to a magnetic field?

I'm thinking the conservation of energy expression needs to be combined with conservation of momentum to make sense, but I'm having trouble here too.

By symmetry, I'd expect the changes in momentum between the electrons to be equal and opposite, cancelling each other out. Since both electrons start at rest, the initial momentum for them is $0$. Also since the field is initially purely electrostatic, there is no momentum in the field.

I would think then, the total momentum remains 0, yet how can it? The total momentum of the electrons has to remain 0. Some radiation leaves the system carrying energy and momentum, so the associated momentum there has to be non-zero. If that is the case though, the combined momentum of the system is non-zero contradicting the conservation of momentum.

I think I'm missing something, but I'm not quite sure what. Any thoughts?

Comment: See [Abraham-Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force).

Comment: What if the momentum carried in the EM field is symmetric? what is its sum?

Comment: $S$ here is not exactly the "energy in the radiation field"; instead, it is just the right correction quantity to make the equation correct. If you want to write down an equation that expresses conservation of energy, you have to take into account all contributions. It is not appropriate to call the correction term "radiation energy", because the correction takes into account also the fact the non-radiative part of EM field (decreasing with distance faster than $1/r$) is not equal to the Coulomb field, but has non-conservative component depending on velocity of the particles.

Comment: This problem can be consistently analyzed within the class theories of charged point particles, where particles do not act on themselves (such as Frenkel's theory): write down the field due to each particle, assuming some particular solution to the Maxwell equations, typically it is assumed the field due to each particle is exactly the retarded solution (see Lienard-Wiechert potentials, and their corresponding fields, given by the Heaviside-Feynman formulae). Then use those field to write down the Lorentz force in the relativistic equation of motion.

Comment: The other forces than the Coulomb force are all there - the velocity correction to electric force, the magnetic force, the acceleration-dependent forces (including force of radiation's electric field) all terms properly retarded (expressed as function of the correct past time). This will produce a long expression and I'm not sure one can derive from it a pretty conservation equation, because of the retardation. This is why fields are so pervasive in EM theories, it is hard to express things only in terms of current state of particles, one has to refer either to their past state, or use fields.

Comment: If you allow expression for $S$ to refer to fields, then there is a nice formula in Frenkel's theory, expressing EM energy as an integral of a sum of pair-wise products of all individual fields present (here, two).